# What if your android app programatically clicks admob ads?

Tags: android, admob

I am new to admob ads for android and I know that the way it works if that you get revenue for every click. But I want to know what happens if a developers adds code that auto clicks an ad once in a while, in a production app? Something like `mAdView.performClick()`. Is that allowed and what happens if you do it?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AdMob terms and conditions, rather than programming.

Comment: Your Admob account gets blocked.

Comment: Interesting question friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will violate the AdMob policy:**"Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods. Testing your own ads by clicking on them is not allowed."**

From this link: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

You account may be banned forever if they detect you do so.

Comment: How can you test your production ad is working if the publisher can't click ads?

Comment: They have a testing mode you can put it into.  They consider clicking on real ads "click fraud", because they pay per click.  Even if they are paying per impression instead, it screws with metrics for ad buyers and makes the ad network less trusted.  So they're very serious about tracking it down.